# How to set a specific user on IIS Application

Tags: c#, .net, iis, virtual-directory

I have inherited some code that creates a couple of applications under IIS 7.0 using code similar to the following (tidied up for brevity)

```
DirectoryEntry iisServer = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/W3SVC/1");
DirectoryEntry folderRoot = iisServer.Children.Find("Root", "IIsWebVirtualDir");
DirectoryEntry newVirDir = folderRoot.Children.Add("MyNewVirtualDir", "IIsWebVirtualDir");

newVirDir.Properties["AccessRead"][0] = true;
newVirDir.Properties["AccessScript"][0] = true;
newVirDir.Properties["Path"].Insert(0, "C:\\MyVirtualDirStuff");
newVirDir.Properties["AccessExecute"][0] = true;
newVirDir.Properties["AppIsolated"].Value = 2; //"Medium (Pooled)"
newVirDir.Properties["DefaultDoc"][0] = "index.htm";
newVirDir.Invoke("AppCreate", true);
newVirDir.CommitChanges();
folderRoot.CommitChanges();
iisServer.CommitChanges();
```

This all works correctly but now I have a need to specify that the Application runs under a specific account.  I can change this manually in IIS in the Connect As... dialog and specify the required domain username and password.

Unfortunately, I cannot for the life of me work out how to set this in the code.
I have tried setting the Username property in various ways but the Invoke("AppCreate") call always throws an Exception of some type dependent on what I've tried.  The following have all failed to work:

```
newVirDir.Username = "MYDOMAIN\\MyUser";
newVirDir.Properties["Username"][0] = "MYDOMAIN\\MyUser";
newVirDir.Properties["Username"].Insert(0, "MYDOMAIN\\MyUser");
```

It must be easy - if only I knew how to do it!

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 5):

I haven't done this in awhile, but I think you need to also create an ApplicationPool, and set the credentials at the Application Pool level, then when you create your virtual directory, make sure it is using the Application Pool that you created.

**This Link should get you started:**

http://martinnormark.com/adding-an-application-pool-to-iis7-programmatically

Then, you'll need to change the code where it specifies use the Network Service, to the following, and you should be in business. (this will set the credentials on the app pool)

```
myAppPool.ProcessModel.IdentityType = ProcessModelIdentityType.SpecificUser;
myAppPool.ProcessModel.UserName = "username";
myAppPool.ProcessModel.Password = "password";
```

Make sure you create the Application Pool first, then set the AppPool on the Virtual Directory like this...

```
newVirDir.Properties["AppPoolId"][0] = "newAppPoolName";
```

Comment: Thanks - there is already an Application Pool and I have set the credentials as required on that but with the Application itself still set to 'Application user (pass-through authentication)' it doesn't work.  I have found that unless I explicitly set the credentials on the Application itself then it seems to be using 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' as the user.  Setting the credentials on the Application itself in IIS ensures that it all works OK but I cannot work out how to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've found *a* way of doing it - whether it's the recommended way I don't know.

Using this link as a start: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application/virtualDirectory

I've now got this, which seems to do exactly what I want:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
  Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
  ConfigurationSection sitesSection = config.GetSection("system.applicationHost/sites");
  ConfigurationElementCollection sitesCollection = sitesSection.GetCollection();
  ConfigurationElement siteElement = FindElement(sitesCollection, "site", "name", @"Default Web Site");
  ConfigurationElementCollection applicationCollection = siteElement.GetCollection();
  ConfigurationElement applicationElement = FindElement(applicationCollection, "application", "path", @"/MyNewVirtualDir");
  ConfigurationElementCollection virtualDirCollection = applicationElement.GetCollection();
  ConfigurationElement virtualDirElement = FindElement(virtualDirCollection, "virtualDirectory", "path", @"/");
  virtualDirElement.Attributes["userName"].Value = "MYDOMAIN\\MyUser";
  virtualDirElement.Attributes["password"].Value = "MyPassword";

  serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Virtual directory Credential

```
newVirDir.Properties["AuthFlags"].Value = 5;
newVirDir.Properties["UNCUsername"].Value = "MYDOMAIN\\MyUser";
newVirDir.Properties["UNCPassword"].Value = "password";
```

Comment: You should expand on this, you haven't written enough to clearly explain what your answer is doing.